# Communication between two war files using Rest Api

Tags: rest, tomcat, deployment

I have two war files like client.war and service.war.I deployed in tomcat server.Now i want to call service from client.So I am unable to call.Could anybody help in this to solve this problem ?

Comment: can you add how you are calling the service from the client? As in which library you are using to communicate in rest.
Are you seeing an error, please edit and add that to your question.

Comment: i am runing the client application.There a login page is there at client side.there we enter user name , password and role type. After giving values it was showing 500 error.And i am calling service through url.

Comment: use api call from client to server

Comment: @Anilkumar, but what is the Rest Api ? Apache CXF , Jersey, Spring ?
Unable to call does not help very much ?
Are you getting a HTTP 500, 404 ?

Comment: yes.i.e i developed with spring mvc and with restfull service.

Comment: @Anilkumar, please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have two war files one is client and server.Both are deployed in server.Now when i am running a client application it shows login page.so by entering values and when i click on login it is showing 500 error

Comment: now i need client application has to access service application.
so for that i need to do any modifications ? or what is the procedure to call service ?

Comment: Can you see the error logs on tomcat since it's a HTTP 500 ?